# Filter out parts of text strings using whole String in Excel Table

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-365

I would like to filter out Column B (Code strings combinations separately in rows in a long list) using whole text string from Column A.

What I did is filter out table manually in Column B for couple of strings, but in future I will be getting lots of strings and I need to do that swiftly and efficiently.

In Column C are the results of all the combinations from Column B per row, and there I need values as they are, so no unique values. Because if you look at Column B and combinations, there some of them that have more than single code combined (and that is fine), exact combinations I need to have in results column.

In Column B and C you can see "basis values" in rows, they are predifined and should be there.

I tweaked a bit using this function:

```
=FILTER(Table1;ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CSxxxFX_CE1,CE2_Dxx_Exx_FB0_FMx_GP3_IT0_JH0_LB0_MV1_MW0_NZ0_OZ0_QS0";Table1[Code String])))
```

But it cant feed whole string inside actually...only parts. Similar I did in Power Query....

I would accept VBA solution too..

The Data and workbook are on the link below.

[image]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nQxYcrj_jnv2xf-QX9hwKCjdWdso2QM7/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=101738555398870704584&rtpof=true&sd=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, if I do understand correctly now; the following might work:

[image]

Formula in `E2`:

```
=VSTACK(B2:B3,UNIQUE(FILTER(B4:B374,BYROW(IFERROR(SEARCH(","&TEXTSPLIT(A2,{"_",","})&",",","&B4:B374&","),0),LAMBDA(a,SUM(a))),"None Found")))
```

---

[`TEXTSPLIT()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textsplit-function-b1ca414e-4c21-4ca0-b1b7-bdecace8a6e7) and [`VSTACK()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vstack-function-a4b86897-be0f-48fc-adca-fcc10d795a9c) are rather new functions currently available to users in the ms365 insiders BETA-channels.

---

Without access one could use the following in `C4` (assuming you will bring over `B2:B3` statically:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(B4:B374,LET(X,TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","_"),"_","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")),MMULT(IFERROR(FIND(","&X&",",","&B4:B374&","),0),SEQUENCE(COUNTA(X),,,0))),"None Found"))
```

Comment: Good approacht, but you took Results (Column C) as a filter and that is wrong, it is just result what I wanna have. You need to filter whole string from column A into column B to get column C...in my Column C is what I need to have if I filter column B from column A

Comment: @mirza, why does the results start with basis then? And why empty values? Strange sample

Comment: I dont know how to explain it better. I think I wrote exactly, I have column A with main long string, and wanna to filter it by column B and to get column C, with all the matches that it finds in column B. Basis values are predefined in my table, ahh empty space was accidently, I just saw it - sorry.

Comment: What about all the other rows with the word "basis", why are they not in your desired result?

Comment: Hmm yes they are if you see better Column C, 2x basis rows at the beginning and then the code strings...

Comment: No I don't see them. Scroll down column B and you'll see tons of data that you did not include in your results that are either "Basis" or things like "CE1,CE2,CE3,CE4". So I'm going to ask you one more question before I give up on this: Why do you have two times "Basis" on the top? And why do you leave out all the other values of "Basis" if these rows are 'fixed'? Why just one time the value 'CE1,CE2,CE3,CE4` in your results if it exists so often in the code string column? It makes no sense.

Comment: Ah okay, I wrote the list long, and I need only matches from given string, no matter others I guess. Those 2x basis are the only things that are "additionally". I am trying to tweak your function to adjust it with my data but not sure if that will work properly

Comment: @Mirza, I made one last ditch effort trying to understand your question. Updated my answer where the top two rows uder 'Code String' are always static/compulsary and the rest is filtered based on 'String' where only unique values remain.

Comment: now we are talking!!! Haha! But those functions are still not updated here in the Company, I mean the versions :/ but at home I will check it, I think this should work properly at least from your results. I will write my update later today! Nice handling with new functions, I recently saw them online but didnt do nothing with them...

Comment: last thing, is there any other function that can replace these newer for the same result?

Comment: @Mirza, see edit

Comment: I saw but getting spill error, strangly. Will need to check it in peace, it has to be maybe some mistake by me when converting commas to ; (becasue of region where I am).

Comment: @Mirza a spill error is related to other values in your data blocking the dynamic array to spill results down the column.

Comment: Ah okay it works, but only if it is out of Excel Table format what is a bit strange. But to avoid further convo, you helped me a lot man, I will adjust it now to my needs and try to understand logic behind these functions!!! Merci!